# Expandable table rows in angular 4 with angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

How would you make rows expandable in angular material tables? One requirement is that I need to be using the [angular material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). I would also prefer to use the material accordion to the information provided [here](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview).

I want to click on row and show different information for each column. Im looking for something like below. If you click on row 1, rows 2 and 3 appear with different data.

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to show the information?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6095#issuecomment-334830404) by Andrew Seguin this is already feasible out of the box: using the `when` predicate.

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows (thx to Lakston)

[image: demo]

Inside of the `mat-table` tag you have to use the `mat-row` component with a `matRipple` directive. When you click on a row the row element will be assigned to the `expandedElement` variable:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
        matRipple 
        class="element-row" 
        [class.expanded]="expandedElement == row"
        (click)="expandedElement = row">
</mat-row>
```

But now we have to add our expanded row, that is hidden by default and will be shown if the user clicks on the row above:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']; when: isExpansionDetailRow"
        [@detailExpand]="row.element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
        style="overflow: hidden"> 
</mat-row>
```

Important is here the already mentioned `when` predicate. This calls a `isExpansionDetailRow` function that is defined in the component itself and checks if the row has a `detailRow` property:

```
isExpansionDetailRow = (row: any) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');
```

**Since RC0** the first param is the index:

```
isExpansionDetailRow = (i: number, row: any) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');
```

If you want to have an expanded view for every row, you have to add an "ExpansionDetailRow" identified by the `detailRow` property for every row like this:

```
connect(): Observable<Element[]> {
    const rows = [];
    data.forEach(element => rows.push(element, { detailRow: true, element }));
    return Observable.of(rows);
}
```

If you would log the `rows` variable to the console output, it will look like this:

[image: console output]

### EDIT: COMPLETE EXAMPLE USING DIRECTIVE

[Mat Table expandable rows (sorting, pagination and filtering)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sorting)

Comment: Is there a way to grab the index in an individual cell so that only that cell is clickable? 

Also, this `when` solution is very nice! I'm injecting a details component that retrieves additional data from the API, so I'm not sure that would make sense here.

Comment: Nevermind. I see that you can do `let row; let index = index` right in the cell definition to receive the row properties.

Comment: This is amazing, I'm wondering if someone might be able to give me a hand with how to implement it in a material table that has pagination, sorting and filtering as in the last example found here https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples?

Comment: @David Here's an example with pagination, sorting and filtering: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sorting (thx to [shlomiassaf](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6095#issuecomment-348007549)). It uses another approach that is better for this case than in the example above.

Comment: @PhilippKief Thanks a lot for all this! Very helpful! Any idea on how to trigger the expand row without click? Like an icon inside the the row itself? I've been trying a few things but it seems hard to refer it without `@Host` annotations..

Comment: I can't get this working, should isExpansionDetailRow fire every time I click a row? Also, if I set it to true, it will override the original row instead of adding a new one.

Comment: How does `isExpansionDetailRow` work?  When I use the following example from the demo page, `whenFn = (_i: number, d: DemoDataObject) => d.value;` it just replaces the regular rows with the expansion rows

Comment: This solution unfortunately does not support pagination and sorting!

Comment: This could work with sort and pagination, it just need to do the double line in the observable at last: `this.getDetailRow(this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data])))`.  where getDetailRow returns an array with `element, { detailRow: true, element: element }`

Comment: @PhilippKief .. Great answer. Is it possible to add another table inside the row?? Is it feasible in Material Table?

Comment: @David I added a solution at the bottom with pagination and column sorting if you're still interested

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sticky' of undefined`

Comment: Hi, thank you for above answer. i need to add column filters to above collapsible table. can you help me to do it?

Comment: @PhilippKief Is there a way to know if a row is expanded or not. I want to use this to render different icons in a certain column. I am using the directive cdkDetailRowDirective.

Comment: For some reason, `connect()` is not getting called in my case, can anyone help ? 
Thanks

Comment: Here's another example that uses multiTemplateDataRows so you can define multiple rows without having to duplicate the data: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ygdrrokyvkv?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html

Comment: anyone have any idea how to get this working with paginator and sorting

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible out of the box, but you can solve it with a little custom code. Take a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5936) and [this solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZL6OnWwVmOCPYetp96XX?p=preview) (not from me, but the basis for this answer).

In short: Use the material table and add a click-method to the rows:

```
<md-row *mdRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let index=index" (click)="expandRow(index, row)" #myRow></md-row>
```

Add a component for the expanded area. The `row_detail.html` contains the html which is in the expanded area.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inline-message',
  templateUrl: 'row_detail.html',
  styles: [`
    :host {
      display: block;
      padding: 24px;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
    }
  `]
})
export class InlineMessageComponent {
  @Input() content1: string;
  @Input() content2: string;
}
```

In your component where the table lives you need the method to expand the row. First, add this to your component...

```
expandedRow: number;
@ViewChildren('myRow', { read: ViewContainerRef }) containers;
```

... and then add the method:

```
/**
   * Shows the detail view of the row
   * @param {number} index
   */
expandRow(index: number, row: DataFromRowFormat) {

    if (this.expandedRow != null) {
      // clear old message
      this.containers.toArray()[this.expandedRow].clear();
    }

    if (this.expandedRow === index) {
      this.expandedRow = null;
    } else {
      const container = this.containers.toArray()[index];
      const factory: ComponentFactory<InlineMessageComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(InlineMessageComponent);
      const messageComponent = container.createComponent(factory);

      messageComponent.instance.content1= "some text";
      messageComponent.instance.content2 = "some more text";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, I think because I'm working with a custom datasource, thanks very much

Comment: this is the thing i was searching and this suits my needs . Thanks :)

Comment: I like this solution, creating a dynamic component better than the solution shown by @Philipp Kief above (let's call that one dynamic row). The dynamic row solution starts to cause some grief around pagination and sorting as it is messing with the rows of the table. This solution, dynamic component, also gives you the ability to easily do everything else with the component that you would normally do.

Comment: add `this.expandedRow = index` at the end of the `else` block in the `expandRow` method

Comment: Check out this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamically-creating-components-animations-ng?file=app%2Falert.component.ts) to implement animation when the dynamic component is created and destroyed with each click

Comment: in angular 7 replace 
this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory
with 
this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory
and add a constructor to ComponentFactoryResolver

Answer (score 2):

When CDK was the only way to get something close to a `Material Table`, using `md-row`'s in a regular table was a viable alternative, but since `@angular/material 2.0.0-beta.12` ditched `CDK` tables and now have their own Data Tables that might fit your needs. See documentation below:

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with Angular Material. This example includes pagination and one example with mat-sort-header on the 'name' column. I had to override mat paginator and do a custom sort to make sure the expandable row was still by its parent when it was sorted. This example also allows you to open multiple rows at a time and to close all rows

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-zs6rfz

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for only using Angular, we can do the Table row expand and collapse option.

I have given [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zarnwz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

In the TS file, we have created a variable to store table data.

```
data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Abc',
      email: 'abc@mail.com',
      isExpand: false,
      address: [
        {
          add1: 'Delhi',
          add2: 'Bangalore',
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Xyz',
      email: 'xyz@mail.com',
      isExpand: false,
      address: [
        {
          add1: 'Mumbai',
          add2: 'Pune',
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'ijk',
      email: 'ijk@mail.com',
      isExpand: false,
      address: [
        {
          add1: 'Chennai',
          add2: 'Bangalore',
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'def',
      email: 'def@mail.com',
      isExpand: false,
      address: [
        {
          add1: 'Kolkata',
          add2: 'Hyderabad',
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

In the HTML file, we have a table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>SL</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of data">
      <tr>
        <td (click)="row.isExpand = !row.isExpand">
          <span *ngIf="!row.isExpand">+</span>
          <span *ngIf="row.isExpand">-</span>
        </td>
        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.email }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="row.isExpand">
        <td colspan="4">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <th>Address1</th>
              <th>Address2</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let row2 of row.address">
                <td>{{ row2.add1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ row2.add2 }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```