# Angular 2 material design <mat-expansion-panel> expand all / collapse all

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to implement expand all and collapse all in angular 2 material. Can any one give idea? how to do that?

Comment: Maybe with the **[expansion panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)** ? Otherwise, we're not doing your job for you, provide some code and/or what you already tried.

Comment: yes this expansion panel only, but I have toggle button to expand all / collapse all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expandable table rows in angular 4 with angular material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123854/expandable-table-rows-in-angular-4-with-angular-material)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1- You should remove the `mat-accordion` to enable multiple expanded panels.

2- Use the `expanded` parameter to change multiple states at the same time.

[Here is a running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49230894)

**EDIT**

From version [6.0.0-beta-0](https://github.com/angular/material2/compare/5.2.0...6.0.0-beta-0) you can use `multi` parameter and the `openAll` and `closeAll` functions :

1- Change the `mat-accordion` element to set the `muti` to true and get the `MatAccordionComponent` instance :

```
<mat-accordion #accordion="matAccordion" [multi]="true">
```

2- Then use the `openAll` and `closeAll` functions to open or close all panels :

```
<button (click)="accordion.openAll()">Expand All </button>
<button (click)="accordion.closeAll()">Collapse All </button>
```

[Here is a running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49230894-3)

Comment: this will not work for version 7. Need to use `multi` to `true` for `accordin`

Comment: Still working with version 7 : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49230894-2, the accordion with multi to true also works : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49230894-3 . I'll edit my post with the multi solution.

Answer (score 7):

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-7-8-add-expansion-panel-accordion-in-angular-project-using-material/)**

For the latest version of Angular material 8

[image]

**Template**

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="openAllPanels()"><b>Open Panels</b></button> &nbsp;
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="closeAllPanels()"><b>Close Panels</b></button>

<mat-accordion [multi]="true"
#accordion="matAccordion"
>
  <mat-expansion-panel 
  #mapanel="matExpansionPanel"
  >
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <b>Title</b>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>Description</p>
    <mat-action-row>
        <button mat-flat-button (click)="mapanel.close()">Click to close</button>
    </mat-action-row>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

**Component**

```
import { MatAccordion } from '@angular/material';

...
...

@ViewChild('accordion',{static:true}) Accordion: MatAccordion


...

...

closeAllPanels(){
    this.Accordion.closeAll();
}
openAllPanels(){
    this.Accordion.openAll();
}


...
...
```

Comment: Not working for me if i set the property `static` to `true`. Must be `false` since angular material 8.2.3.

Comment: If you add [multi]="true" to mat-accordion and your answer will work and be full and better

Answer (score 2):

To use a toggle button (instead of 2 buttons like ibenjelloun's answer), you can use this in the template:

`<button (click)="toggleExpandState()">{{ allExpandState ? "Collapse All" : "Expand All" }}</button>`

and add this in the component:

`toggleExpandState() {
    this.allExpandState = !this.allExpandState;
}`

This introduces a problem where if you expand all the panels manually, the button will still say "Expand All" and vice versa, so you could add a listener when expanding/collapsing a single panel to check if all the panels are expanded or collapsed, and change the variable `allExpandState` accordingly.

Also, you don't have to remove the `mat-accordian`, just add `multi="true"` to it.