# material angular table multiple rows directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

I want to make an expandable datatable using mat-table from [material angular 2](https://material.angular.io/). A row CAN contain subrows.

My rows data is an object that can contain other sub-objects.

Using material angular table component or mat-table, it is possible to define multiple rows types and chose which one to apply to the current iteration.

---

But is there a way to generate multiple kind of rows during the same iteration ?

Am I forced to add the sub-items to the datasource that feeds the mat-tabke, or it possible to give it items that contain sub-items and generate 1 row with the item data and 1 row for each sub-item ?

---

I tried to follow the model from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931989/6115238).

So I have these rows defined in my component.ts

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let rule; columns: ['expandedDetail']; when: isExpansionDetailRow"
                 [@detailExpand]="rule.element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
                 style="overflow: hidden">
        </mat-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let rule; columns: ['expandedDetail']; when: isExpansionDetailRow"
                 [@detailExpand]="rule.element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
                 style="overflow: hidden">
        </mat-row>
```

But it seems that when the isExpansionDetail is true and the second row type is chosen, it 'overrides' the first one, which wont be generated.

Comment: I had same issue, solved it with plain old `<div>`.

Comment: @BlackBeard Can you expand a bit on this ? Did you use only divs or put a div somewhere in the template ? Or a div in the mat row to emulate a conditional row ?

Comment: I created the entire table using **only** `<div>`.

Comment: @BlackBeard But how were you able to benefit from the mat-table functionalities then ?

Comment: Do you mean `mat-table`?

Comment: @BlackBeard Yes, typo. I meant how can you use sort, pagination and all if you use divs ?

Comment: I did not used any feature of `mat-table`. I think people using `<div>` will have to write those logic manually.

Comment: @BlackBeard I see thanks for explanation. But I should use mat-table

Answer (score 7):

Check if this work for you, add the next attribute to your table **multiTemplateDataRows**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" multiTemplateDataRows>
```

Read more about here https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/api