# How to expand all rows by default in material table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on achieving expandable rows with `material table`. I have followed  below reference for the same

[Stack Overflow : Expandable-table-rows-in-angular-4-with-angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123854/expandable-table-rows-in-angular-4-with-angular-material)

I wanted to expand all rows by default. But I am not sure how can achieve that.

[Stackblitz Demo | Expandable rows](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows-71p7mn?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts)

Any advice and suggestions will be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the same logic with only having one row collapsable at once, but having them all start as expanded, you can just change

```
[@detailExpand]="row.element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
```

To

```
[@detailExpand]="row.element != expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
```

If you want a fully functional table with expand/collapsable elements, you could add a new property called '**expanded**' to your **Element** interface:

```
export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  expanded: boolean;
}
```

You can then add a default value of **true** to your new property in the datasource:

```
const data: Element[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H', expanded: true },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He', expanded: true  }
 ...
];
```

Lastly, change your row logic to use the **expanded** property instead of selected element:

Change:

```
[class.expanded]="expandedElement == row"
(click)="expandedElement = row"
...
[@detailExpand]="row.element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
```

To:

```
[class.expanded]="row.expanded"
(click)="row.expanded = !row.expanded"
...
[@detailExpand]="row.element.expanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
```

Don't forget to clear away the unused code!

Answer (score 2):

Check this [Expand all rows on button click](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfny52?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)

Comment: `[@detailExpand]="(row.element == expandedElement || true) ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"`   did the trick